# Select2 initSelection deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am now creating a Rails project and I am using `select2` for the form.

form_for in View:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient_fields|%>
     Ingredients: <%= ingredient_fields.select(:name, @ingredients,
     {}, multiple: true)%>
   <% end %>
```

javascript file:

```
$('#cuisine_ingredients_name').select2();
```

I set `@ingredients` in the controller and this is working as it should be, but I don't know how to set the multiple default values for this `select2` form.

It seems like `initSelection` method is deprecated in [version 4.0.0](http://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html), and I couldn't find a good example using a new method.

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What HTML is generated by rails for the `<select multiple>`? There should be a way through rails to mark options are pre-selected. [The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) seems to suggest a `:suggested` option exists.

Comment: yes, `<select multiple>` is being generated, but I don't know where to set the :suggested option. I tried below but this did not work.
`<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do, :suggested=>1 |ingredient_fields|%>`
this does not throw any error either.

Comment: My bad, it's not `:suggested` it's `:selected`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after working on this for a while, I figured it out myself.

```
  <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient_fields|%>
 Ingredients: <%= ingredient_fields.select(:name, @ingredients,
 {selected: @selected_ingredients}, multiple: true)%>
```

Adding a selected option to `select` worked for me, as Kevin suggested (Thank you!).

In this example, `@selected_ingredients` is defined in edit method in cuisines_controller.

Thank you all for your help!